# Returning an arraylist to be accessed from another class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jtable

I'm new to Stackoverflow, so here goes.

I'm currently working on an assignment that requires to read from a csv file and place it into some sort of data collection.

I've gone with an arraylist. But what I seem to be stuck with is that I'm attempting to use my ReadWriteFile class to read the csv file into an arraylist (which works). But I need to somehow access that array in my GUI class to fill my JTable with said data.

After looking through similar help requests, I haven't been able to find any success.

My current code from my ReadWriteFile class;

```
public static void Read() throws IOException {

    String lines = "";
    String unparsedFile = "";
    String dataArray[];
    String col[] = { "COUNTRY", "MILITARY", "CIVILIAN", "POWER" };

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/Corbin/Desktop/IN610 - Assignment 1/Programming3_WWII_Deaths.csv");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
        unparsedFile = unparsedFile + lines;
    }
    br.close();

    dataArray = unparsedFile.split(",");

    for (String item : dataArray) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }

    ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        myArrayList.add(dataArray[i]);
    }
}
```

So what my question is; How can I create a method that returns the values from the array, so I can access that array in my GUI class and add each element to my JTable?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `void` you can change the method to return an `ArrayList`.
Something like this `public static List<String> Read() throws IOException {// some code 
return myArrayList}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple example of how to return array in the method and how to use it in GUI class:

```
public class Main {

    public String[] readFromFile (String filePath) {

        ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            // read file content to yourList
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return yourList.toArray(new String[yourList.size()]);
    }
}
```

And the GUI class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JTable jTable;

    public GUI() {
        jTable = new JTable(10, 10);
        this.getContentPane().add(jTable);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
    }

    public void passArrayToTable(Main mainClass) {

        String[] array = mainClass.readFromFile("C:\\file.csv");

        // for (String s : array) {
        // add values to jTable with: jTable.setValueAt(s,row,column);
        // }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI().passArrayToTable(new Main());
    }
}
```